# How to prevent docker container from stopping after executing sh script file

Tags: bash, shell, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

im running a docker container as shown below, after the sh files are executed the container terminate by default, how i can keep the container working in background

sample from docker file

```
#=========================
# Copying Scripts to root
#=========================
COPY entry_point.sh \
 /root/

RUN chmod +x /root/entry_point.sh

#=======================
# framework entry point
#=======================
CMD /root/entry_point.sh
```

the entry_point.sh file

```
function clone_repo() {
mkdir /root/repo
git clone git@github.com:test/tests.git /root/repo && \
rm -rf /root/.ssh
}

clone_repo
```

and here is the command im using to initialize the container

```
docker run -p 5900:5900 --name mycontainer--privileged amrka/image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing entry_point

Answer (score 3):

You could also run `CMD /root/entry_point.sh; sleep infinity`

Answer (score 0):

Thats how docker container works, its goes offf when application dies.
Why you need it to keep alive?
What it will do?
if you want just to have, you can run `sleep 10000000` for example at end of the file, so it will keep container, but why?
if you want execute any tas on schedule, then you can use any cron image.